# After commit successfully, the Sourcetree committing window didn't close automatically

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree

After I upgrade Sourcetree to version 3.1.1, everytime I commit something successfully, the committing window didn’t close automatically. How can I fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello @MissYasiky I'm not 100% sure but this happen when you expand the pop-up while you're pushing your code. If you keep the pop-up collapsed it will automatically hide.

[image]

When you push the code you see this pop-up. If you don't click on the `Show Full Output` it will automatically hide and if click on the `Show Full Output` button it will provide you the necessary details with a close button to hide the view.

I Hope that helps.

**Edit**

[I Just tested it and works fine](https://vimeo.com/user96883029/review/327663146/4c1ffd41c4)

Comment: And, just cos I got frustrated with my situation, make sure to check you have "Always display full console output" checked, otherwise that button shows in the popup for less than a second, disappears, and there's no way to unclick it.